# Перево́дный и переводно́й. Особенности употребления

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов

В каких случаях употребляется слово **перево́дный**, а в каких — **переводно́й**?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру указует:

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x)

> **ПЕРЕВОДН*О*Й**, -ая, -ое; *(офиц.)* **ПЕРЕВ*О*ДНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. Предназначенный, служащий для перевода денег (по телеграфу, по почте,
>   через банк). *П. бланк. П. вексель. П. рубль* (денежная единица для
>   безналичных расчётов). 2. Переведённый с какого-л. языка. *П-ая
>   литература. П. роман.* 3. Такой, который переводится или служит для
>   перевода, копировки. *П-ая бумага* (=копировальная бумага). *П-ые
>   картинки. П. рисунок.* 4. Связанный с переводом на следующую ступень
>   обучения. *П. балл. П-ые экзамены, списки.* 5. *Техн.*
>   Предназначенный, служащий для перевода, перехода на что-л. другое (на
>   другой путь, на другую скорость и т.п.). *П. брус. П-ые механизмы. П.
>   клапан.*

Из-за сокращений мне (например) непонятно, считает ли Кузнецов употребление слов перево́дный — переводно́й синонимичным, отличающимся лишь стилистически.

А вот [Русское словесное ударение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x) знать не знает никакого перево́дного, а этот словарь стоит над Кузнецовым (уже не раз ловленным [на грубых ошибках](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)):

> переводн**о**й; переводн**о**й балл; переводн**ы**е экзамены;
>   переводн**а**я картинка; переводн**о**й роман; переводн**о**й бланк;
>   переводн**о**й рубль

Но я вполне допускаю, что кузнецовский пункт 5 с пометой *техн.* действительно может относится к профессиональной лексике и звучать как перево́дный:

перево́дный брус; перево́дные механизмы; перево́дный клапан.

Comment: Вот тут: Переводный бланк. Переводный вексель. Переводная литература. Переводный роман. Переводная бумага. Переводный балл. Переводной брус. Переводные механизмы. Переводный клапан. Переводный рубль. http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/16/ma305216.htm?cmd=p&istext=1

Comment: Да, Римуся, переводный роман - это круто-клёво! Мы пойдём другим путём! И всё-таки - Русское словесное ударение рулит!

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Резниченко (2010 год) указаны обе формы: ***переводнОй и перевОдный*,** как и в большинстве словарей того времени. Нет сомнений, что эти формы сосуществовали ранее, но в настоящее время частотность слова ***переводнОй*** значительно выше (в Нацкорпусе (177: 28).

Это связано с тем, что эти слова являются **синонимами практически во всех своих значениях,** поэтому один из вариантов стал устаревать.

Для сравнения такие пары, как *домовый и домовой*, *языковый и языковой*  различаются по семантике, поэтому в языке сохраняются обе формы.

Примеры:

для слова ***переводный*** (поздний вариант):

Однажды, читая какой‑то итальянский **переводный роман...** [Н. О. Лосский. Воспоминания: жизнь и философский путь (1968)];

для слова ***переводной*** (ранний вариант):

Там ― **переводной роман** этакого, знаете ли, Гэмфри Уорда, что ли! [M. К. Первухин. Из воспоминаний о Чехове (1915)].